# Create image from black and white 1D-array pixels

Tags: java, image, rgb

How can I create a black and white image using array of BLACK and WHITE pixels ?

```
int pixels[]= {-1, -16777216,-16777216,-16777216....}
Color w = new Color(Color.WHITE.getRGB());
int wi = w.getRGB();

Color b = new Color(Color.BLACK.getRGB());
int bi = b.getRGB();
```

I was trying to use this code but the result was only few black pixels.

```
  public static BufferedImage getImageFromArray(int[] pixels, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
        raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are tying to create, but here are some nice examples: 
http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/1100-create-bw.jsp